# How to find keys in a Dict<int,List<Tuple<string,string>>> such that the list contains elements with given Item1 and Items

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, string>>> L` and I want to find in it all keys such that the corresponding value, a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`, has tuples such that Item1 and Item2 are equal to some given values "toto" and "tata".

I tried like below:

```
var res = L.Where(x => x.Value.ToList().Where(y => y.Item1 == "toto" && 
                           (string) y.Item2 == "tata").Any()).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

I am not happy with the error handling in my code line : what is some of the intermediate result of `Where`'s is null etc. What is the vanilla c# way for doing this ?

Comment: Not sure what you asking. Title is how to find, question about error handling. How about vanilla `try-catch` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, string>>>();

...

var keys = d.Where(x => x.Value.Any(y => y.Item1 == val1 && y.Item2 == val2))
            .Select(x => x.Key);
```

If you are worried about null lists

```
var keys = d.Where(x => x.Value != null && x.Any(y => y.Item1 == val1 && y.Item2 == val2))
            .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Or with much nicer named Tuples

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, List<(string val1, string val2)>();

...

var keys = d.Where(x => x.Value != null && x.Value.Any(y => y.val1 == val1 && y.val2 == val2))
            .Select(x => x.Key);
```